# Notify user for video chat

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to place OpenTok video calls within my website. How do I notify a particular user for video chat?

```
var apiKey = "447302";
var sessionId = "1_MX40NDczMDE5Mn5";
var token = "T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NDczMDE5MiZzZGtfdmVyc2l";

// Initialize session, set up event listeners, and connect
var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);
session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', sessionConnectedHandler);
session.connect(apiKey, token);

function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
    var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, 'myPublisherDiv');
    session.publish(publisher);
}


session.on("streamCreated", function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.streams.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + e.streams[i].streamId);
        document.getElementById('chatDiv').appendChild(div);
        session.subscribe(e.streams[i], e.streams[i].streamId);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenTok's API does not provide any notification logic. You can notify users by playing a sound or sending alert messages.

When a new person joins your session, you will get a connectionCreated event. You can throw a notification on your connectionCreated handler.